# Youtube Api in Php Mysql to get all videos

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, youtube-api

Youtube Api in Php Mysql to get all videos from multiple channels subscribe by me ,I want to show them on my website with their respective categories ,but i don't find any suitable API .

I also want to use search on my website using youtube API and show all the results provided by api on my webpage .

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should get the ids of all channels by using the youtube api.then  use the  iframe for diplay the tag in respectively category.and for the search also use the youtube api,such as https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=q_WvU9J1nXw&key={YOUR_API_KEY} for searchings
Vivek Kumar

Answer (score -2):

Check this [code](http://pastebin.com/SkYqU3f9) in pastebin to see the solution for your question.

Comment: Yes, you can't just link to the solution without any explanation or what your solution actually is. Can't you paste the code, or the main portion of it in your answer, then supply an external demo ? Also, try to explain why your solution is useful and how it works.